# question on my helper method using self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I created this helper method. In my view I call it with `days_left(duedate)`. I dont really like my helper. Is it possible to use it with `self`. Since I dont really know how self is being used. Is it the same as `this` in java or javascript? What object is it related to? Feel free to tune this method. Thx for your time!

```
def days_left(duedate)
  (if duedate.date == Date.today
    "Today"
  elsif duedate.date-Date.today < 1
    "expired"
  elsif duedate.date-Date.today == 1
    "Tomorrow"
  else
    "#{(duedate.date-Date.today).to_i}"
  end).to_s.html_safe
end
```

Comment: Self is related to the object in a model. I don't see how you could use it there

Comment: Did you have a look at the vode of http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words

Comment: thx for your reply. So a Model Object is an object I create in my action `new` like `@duedate = Duedate.new`? how could I use `self` with it?

Answer (score 1):

You might try moving this method to your model.

This would be similar to adding a 'full_name' method to a model with the attributes 'first_name' and 'last_name.' You wouldn't store 'full_name' separately in your database, because that would result in redundant, denormalized data.

For example:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    def full_name
        "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
    end
end
```

So you could similarly add the 'days_left' method to your model, which fits there because it's adding a friendlier version of an existing data attribute.